# Removing one item from a listview

Tags: java, android

I have a list of items and every item has a button that must remove the specified item. The problem I encounter is that when I press the button, it removes all the items. Here is the code that I am using:

```
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View costumView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_costum_raw, parent, false);

    final JSONObject object = (JSONObject) getItem(position);
    TextView productName = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.cartProductName);
    TextView productQuantity = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.cartProductQuantity);
    TextView productPrice = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.cartProductPrice);

    ImageView productPicture = (ImageView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.cartProductImage);

    Button remove = (Button) costumView.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);

    remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clear();
            JSONObject serverResponse = null;
            try {
                RemoveProductRequest removeProductRequest = new RemoveProductRequest(object.get("user_id").toString() , object.get("product_id").toString() , object.get("dispensary_id").toString());
                String response = removeProductRequest.doInBackground();
                serverResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    try
    {
        Glide.with(this.getContext()).load(object.getString("image")).into(productPicture);
        productName.setText(object.get("name").toString());
        productQuantity.setText(productQuantity.getText() + object.get("quantity").toString() + " grams");
        productPrice.setText(productPrice.getText() + "$" + object.get("prod_price").toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return costumView;

}
```

This is the adapter that I am using to create the items from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are calling `clear()` inside the adapter. It will clear all adapter items. Read docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear()

If you want to remove only one item, try to call `remove`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove(T)